# Trying to reset input field with form reset() function but not working

Tags: javascript, html, function, reset, codepen

I'm trying to create a sort of posting system and it works for the most part, but when the post button is clicked, the input field doesn't get reset. I tried a bunch of different ways and none of them have worked, so here is the last one I tried (CodePen sets up the skeleton code so it wouldn't be the problem) :

HTML:

```
<form id="post" name="write">
    <div class="textbox">
        <input class="postwriter" name="post" type="text" placeholder="What's on your mind?" id="myPost">
        <button id="Post" onclick= "return write_below(this); return formReset();" value="submit" >Post</button>
    </div>
</form>
<div class="posts" id="postDisplay">
    <p class="para"><span id='display'></span></p>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function write_below(form) {
    var input = document.forms.write.post.value;
    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML += "<p>" + Math.floor(Math.random()*20) + ": " + input + "</p>" + "<br/>";
    return false;
}
function formReset(){
    document.getElementById("post").reset();
}
```

Comment: You have two elements with the `id` of `post` (the form and the button). In HTML case doesn't matter.  All ids should be unique.

Comment: @ScottMarcus There's no same ID there. JavaScript is CaSe SeNsItIvE.

Comment: @PraveenKumar But, HTML isn't and having ids that differ only by case WILL be an issue with `<a href="#id">` links, in CSS and just plain confusing in JS as well.

Comment: @ScottMarcus You are right.

Comment: @Scott Marcus hmm I wasn't aware of this. I thought all code was case sensitive. I'll try this and see what happens. Thanks!

Comment: HTML and CSS are NOT case-sensitive languages. JavaScript is. But, regardless, having IDs that differ only by case is a recipe for disaster. See: https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/documents.html#case-insensitivity and http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/casesensitivity for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `onclick` looks like this:

```
onclick="return write_below(this); return formReset();"
```

Which translates to:

```
return write_below(this);
return formReset();
```

After the first return, the script ends. So remove the first return. Your code should look like:

```
onclick="write_below(this); formReset(); return false;"
```

Having said that, the `return false` here, makes no sense, so get rid of it.

```
function write_below(form) {
  var input = document.forms.write.post.value;
  document.getElementById('display').innerHTML += "<p>" + Math.floor(Math.random()*20) + ": " + input + "</p>" + "<br/>";
}
```

> ***Note:*** All your IDs look similar, which might make the developers or someone who sees your code mad. Is that your intention?

Comment: The return false was so that it doesn't try to load a new page when I click. And the similar ID's are bc I didn't really know what else to ID them with lol

Comment: @user147219 Man, that's the basic thing. Okay, in case if `return false` doesn't work for you, please remove them altogether.

Comment: @user147219 When giving HTML elements IDs, it's best to prefix the ID with a something that identifies what kind of element it is. For example, your form's id would be `frmPost` and your button would be: `btnPost`. Those are perfectly legitimate because the prefix keeps them from stepping on each others toes. It's also great because in your JavaScript, you'll know when you run into, say `txtPost` that the element is a textbox and then you'll know what kind of properties and methods it has without having to go hunt it down in the HTML.

Comment: @PraveenKumar thank you it worked to reset the text box now i just need to figure out how to have it reset only the textbox lol. thanks tho!